# A movie about people moving at the speed of light

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It's a nice film and I'd like to watch it again. I think it is from the early 2000's. In English language. Not animated. Probably American. These are some scenes which I vaguely remember:

- People able to move very fast (probably with a device or medicine). When in this state, their bodies are glowing. Human eyes cannnot see them.
- There's a scene in which a man/woman is watering plant with a hose. Someone then activates the lightspeed state and the water drops move very slowly (almost stopped in midair).
- There's also a more advanced lightspeed state. In this more advanced state, the user's body glows even more and they're able to move through solid objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Clockstoppers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157472/combined) from 2002.

> Until now, Zak Gibbs' greatest challenge has been finding a way to buy a car. But when he discovers an odd wristwatch amidst his father's various inventions and slips it on, something very strange happens. The world around him seemingly comes to a stop; giving the effect that everyone has come to a stop. Zak quickly learns how to manipulate the device, and he and his quick-witted, beautiful new friend, Francesca, have some real fun. What they soon realize, though, is they are not alone in hypertime.

[Here's the scene with the sprinkler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cFyFvO56Sw), and here's another scene that shows the effects of hypertime you've described, namely that Zack is super fast, glows and can pass through solid objects:

Comment: I never understood why people, when they first discover they can phase through solid objects, decide to spend as much time buried within said objects as possible. You know nothing about this phenomenon; are you not afraid you're going to rematerialise inside your "new friend" (ooh-er) at any time?!

Comment: I've never understood, how once they first discover they can phase through solid objects, it was not by falling into the floor.